# Angular2 Plugin Mechanism

Tags: angular, plugins, webpack, electron

I created a new Angular2 project with angular-cli. I wrapped it into Electron to use it as a desktop application. The app is more or less a simple window with a navbar and a plus sign in the middle. Clicking the plus should allow importing 'Plugins' to enrich the application. Plugins are complete Angular2 Projects itself, coming with their own package.json and dependencies. They could be packaged with webpack if necessary. Is there a way/approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438198/implementing-a-plugin-architecture-plugin-system-pluggable-framework-in-angu Seems to be a similar question. Unfortunately unsolved

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the @Gijs code

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Angular-2-Components/tree/master/angular-2-components-chapter-10

and also can bundle the app by using webpack (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#top) or gulp(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115444/Developing-And-Deploying-An-Angular-Application-Wi).

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, unfortunately :( There is a similar question around http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438198/implementing-a-plugin-architecture-plugin-system-pluggable-framework-in-angu