# How to make modulaire/plugin (Pluggable features) architecture by angular 5/6

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular5, angular6

I want make modulare application

**My request**

> */  A standard app
>
> */ And make possibility to extend standard app by additional plugins
>
> */ the plugin should be pluggable and indepence of the core code
>
> */ both the plugin exist or note apps should work
>
> */ if plugin added and activated some features should be added

Briefly like WordPress approach with the thirdparty plugins

**Questions :**

> 1/ Is it possible ?
>
> 2/ If yes how to de this (Provide some
>   tutorial,docomentation,implementation,snippets ) ?

I hope i'm clear

*Any kind of help mean a lot of to me*

Thank you very much for you

Answer (score 0):

[Implementing a plugin architecture / plugin system / pluggable framework in Angular 2, 4, 5, 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438198/implementing-a-plugin-architecture-plugin-system-pluggable-framework-in-angu) asked already the same questions. There is currently no out-of-the-box solution - close, but not what you and many others are waiting for ...